# Why does Salesforce enqueue my tests to run in the past?

Tags: developer-console, developer

I noticed an issue with salesforce in the developer console today. I should mention that I am using Chrome, on Linux.

When I schedule tests to run, the 'enqueued date' appears as some time several months ago.  Luckily, the tests eventually run.

Anyone seen this before?  Is there a way to fix it?

[image: salesforce_fail]

Comment: I'd assume it's taking a number representation of the date and incorrectly parsing it.  That is 2/9/15 which could be Sep-2 or Feb-9 depending on the locale.  Strange that it gets it wrong though!

Comment: Yeah, good call Nick.  Sounds about right.  Time for Salesforce to fix it :)